# Radio Button check in vanilla javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, html

My radio button checking is not working. Can anyone please help me with this? I
want to check if the radio button is checked or not. if not checked then I want this program to give an alert. But in this program whenever the radio button is not checked I am not getting the alert.

```
 <div>
              <label for="gender">Gender: </label>
              <input type="radio" name="myRadio"> Male
              <input type="radio" name="myRadio"> Female
              <input type="radio" name="myRadio"> Other
          </div>
```

The radio button checking function is given below:

```
function radioCheck(){
              var radio = document.forms["myForm"]["myRadio"].value;
    
                  for (var i=0; i<radio.length; i++) {
                    if (radio[i].checked){
                    break;
                  }else
                  {
                    alert("No radio button is checked");
                  }
              }
    
        }
```

Comment: Can you please explain what do you want to achieve? You want to show alert if nothing is checked but do nothing when something is checked?

Comment: @Sowam I want to check if the radio button is checked or not. if not checked then I want this program to give an alert. But in this program whenever the button is not checked I am not getting the alert.

Comment: You want to give alert when it is checked or not checked? or both? I don't understand your answer... why do you use "break" there? and why there is nothing before it?

Comment: Sowam  I want to give an alert when the radio button is not checked and I have used break because if the checked button is found then the program should terminate from if block.

Comment: I added an answer :) and updated it

Comment: The link you have provided still is not working properly. If I select a radio button it still giving an alert that no radio button is checked. Can you check, please? @Sowam

Comment: That's right, I updated the answer, now it works properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so this is working code:

```
function radioCheck(){
  const radioList = document.getElementsByName("myRadio")
  let notChecked = false;
  
  for(let i = 0; i < radioList.length; i ++){
    if(radioList[i].checked){
        return;
    } else {
        notChecked = true;
    }
   
  }

   if(notChecked){
      alert("No radio button is checked")
    }
}

radioCheck()
```

To explain:

- first of all you have to get all inputs by using `document.getElementsByName` because the only one thing that they have the same is `name` property which is `name="myRadio"` in this example
- second thing I added variable `notChecked` which is false on initial so when it will go through all inputs and see that one of them is not selected if will show alert
- then you just do normal for loop that goes through all elements and checks if they are checked
- if one of them is checked it just stops for loop and returns nothing, otherwise it sets `notChecked = true`
- after loop I just check if `notChecked` value is true and if it is it shows an alert
- last and important thing - you have to run this function at least once to execute it so you just add `radioCheck()` in the end
- I also added this part in html `<button onclick={radioCheck()} > run again </button>`

so after clicking on button `"run again"` you can use it again (just for test)

here is working example:

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/ouj4gvk9/)

hope that my answer will help you out :) if you have any questions please ask